# Conditional independence given joint

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

Let us consider variables $A,B,C,D$ such that

- $A$ is conditionally **independent** of $B$ given $C$, i.e. $A \bot B|C$
- $A$ is conditionally **dependent** on $B$ given $D$, i.e. $A \not\bot B|D$

Are $A$ and $B$ conditionally independent of each other given $C,D$? Are they not? Can we conclude anything about their conditional independence?

That is, can we say anything about the following claim? $A \bot B|C,D$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A situation where $A \perp B \mid C, D$ (dependence arrows run top-to-bottom, i.e. $C \to A$):

```
D       C
      /   \
     A     B
```

A situation where $A \not\perp B \mid C, D$:

```
  C
 / \
A   B
 \ /
  D
```

So we can't say one way or the other.